# How to view purchased items that have not been transferred to mac?

Tags: iphone, big-sur

I connected my iPhone to my new mac which runs macos Big Sur, i get the following message when I want to update my iPhone:

> There are purchased items on the iPhone “myiPhone” that have not been transferred to your Mac. You should transfer these items to your Mac before updating this iPhone. Are you sure you want to continue?

How can I view which purchases this message is talking about? I want to go through them and see if its just stuff I can easily redownload again (like music I bought from iTunes) or if it's other stuff (like stuff I manually put on my phone).

Comment: I've searched for an answer.  I've found nothing.  I can't update to latest iOS from my Mac.  I can't see my "purchases".  This message has happened many times before and I don't know why it keeps happening, but now that I'm on Big Sur, there seems to be no way at all to actually "Transfer" like there was with iTunes.app and clicking the "Continue" button does nothing?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your iOS device to your mac, and choose "Trust This Computer" if prompted.

Launch the Music app on your Mac. Prior to macOS Catalina 10.15 you can use iTunes. Your iOS device should be listed on the left hand-side. Right-click on the iOS device and choose "Transfer Purchases".

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254222467